# How to remove file in Ubuntu Terminal list?

Tags: command-line, pycharm

I have entered command `ls -ld .?*` and then got output like this (here is just part of it which I wish to remove)

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 stanislav stanislav  4096 Apr 22 20:29 .PyCharm2018.3
drwxrwxr-x  4 stanislav stanislav  4096 Apr 22 20:16 .PyCharm2019.2
drwxrwxr-x  4 stanislav stanislav  4096 Mar 23 13:59 .PyCharmCE2019.3
```

So could anybody advice how to make it.
Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S. Already for three hours trying to reinstall PyCharm but it is not starting after installation. Seem I need to remove these files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the find command:

```bsh
find /dir/to/search/ -type f -name ".?*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

You should probably change the `.?*` regexp with a more specific one if you can, to avoid deleting unwanted files.

To test, you can try to print the files first:

```bsh
find /dir/to/search/ -type f -name ".?*" -print
```

Comment: generally I needed to remove directory so found this solution: `rm -r .PyCharm2019.2` anyway it did not help so I gonna to waste a night to reinstall Ubuntu, luckily there is new 20.04 lts revision so lets say it will be upgrade rather then wasting =)